# How to select a dynamic rank value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table of companies and another of employees and the dates they joined the company. I am able to get the 5 most recent hires for each company [as shown here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31821/2). Now, I'd like to only show rank <= 3 for Company A, rank <= 8 for Company B and an unlimited number for Company C. 3, 8 and -1 are stored as the "max" column in the company table. How do I dynamically select the max in this case?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: The `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables. Sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements. The expected result with the given sample data.

Comment: @stickybit . . . The question has a link to SQL Fiddle that has most of this information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes and that is nice, as a bonus. However all the basic information necessary should be on site, so that the question is also comprehensible should the fiddle site go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want:

```
SELECT *  -- choose the columns you want here
FROM (SELECT e.*, c.max,
             row_number() over (partition by company order by joined desc) as rank
      FROM employees e JOIN
           companies c
           on e.company = c.pk
     ) e
WHERE rank < max or max = -1
```